# How to fix slider issue?

Tags: css

I have my Tabs working just fine. If you click on the plus symbol **(+)** you will be able to add Tabs and maybe after adding **3 or 4 tabs** you'll see **tabBar scroller buttons** on both ends. This has been done using ExtJS and it works great!

**Working Code:** 
 [**Example Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/1rwymb7m/9/)

Basically, after certain width I would like to show those **the scroller** that will allow the user to navigate from right-left or left-right. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks a lot in advance!

**Here's my code:**

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0gzArDtBJgLpFKPqDKTA?p=preview)

```
<p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel header="one">
   <button (click)="showSecondTab()">Show Second Tab</button>
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="two">
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="three">
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="fourt">
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="five">
  </p-tabPanel>
   .......
   .......
   .......

</p-tabView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is no built-in feature in primeng package. So I would consider writing some directive which will implement all desired behavior and take all hard work on itself.

This directive is going to have all stuff for handling such events such as `window:scroll`, `click|long click` on arrows, `mousewhell` on tabs. For such things i'm goung to use rxjs streams.

Also it's going to do some DOM manipulation like wrapping tabs in container and creating arrows.

It also will handle changes for `p-tabPanel` components through `ContentChildren.changes`

Finally, the result should look like:

[image]

**tab-scroller.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, NgZone, Input, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

import { TabPanel } from 'primeng/primeng';

import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators/takeUntil';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators/mergeMap';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators/take';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators/delay';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tabScroller]',
})
export class TabScrollerDirective {

  @Input() arrowWidth = 30;
  @Input() shiftWidth = 25;

  @ContentChildren(TabPanel) tabPanels: QueryList<TabPanel>;

  private _container: HTMLElement;
  private _nav: HTMLElement;

  private _shift = 0;
  private _scrollable: boolean;

  private _leftArrow: HTMLElement;
  private _rightArrow: HTMLElement;

  private readonly _destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private elRef: ElementRef,
    private zone: NgZone) { }

  get rightBorder() {
    return -(this._nav.scrollWidth - this._nav.offsetWidth);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.tabPanels.changes
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
      .subscribe(() => {
          this.zone.onStable.asObservable()
            .pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe(() => this._refreshScroller());
        })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.init());
  }

  init() {
    this._nav = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('[role=tablist]');
    this._container = wrap(this._nav, 'nav-wrapper');

    this._initEvents();

    this._leftArrow = this._createArrow('left');
    this._rightArrow = this._createArrow('right');

    this._refreshScroller();
  }

  scroll(shift: number) {
    this._shift += shift;

    const rightBorder = this.rightBorder;
    if (this._shift < rightBorder) {
      this._shift = rightBorder;
    }
    if (this._shift >= 0) {
      this._shift = 0;
    }

    this._leftArrow.classList.toggle('nav-arrow--disabled', this._shift >= 0);
    this._rightArrow.classList.toggle('nav-arrow--disabled', this._shift <= rightBorder);

    this._nav.style.transform = `translateX(${this._shift}px)`;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroyed$.next();
    this._destroyed$.complete();
  }

  private _initEvents() {
    fromEvent(this._container, 'mousewheel')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
      .subscribe((e: any) => this._onMouseWheel(e));
    // Firefox
    fromEvent(this._container, 'DOMMouseScroll')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
      .subscribe((e: any) => this._onMouseWheel(e));
    fromEvent(window, 'resize')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this._refreshScroller();
      });
  }

  private _onMouseWheel(e: any) {
    const delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    this.scroll(delta * 25);
  }

  private _createArrow(direction: string) {
    const arrow = el(`nav-arrow nav-arrow--${direction}`);
    this._container.insertBefore(arrow, this._nav);
    arrow.style.width = this.arrowWidth + 'px';
    fromEvent(arrow, 'click')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroyed$))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.scroll(direction === 'left' ? this.shiftWidth : -this.shiftWidth);
      });

    const upStream$ = fromEvent(arrow, 'mouseup');
    // handle long press
    fromEvent(arrow, 'mousedown')
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._destroyed$),
        mergeMap((event) => interval(100).pipe(delay(100), takeUntil(upStream$)))
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.scroll(direction === 'left' ? this.shiftWidth : -this.shiftWidth);
      });

    return arrow;
  }

  private _refreshScroller() {
    const compareWith = (this._scrollable ? -this.arrowWidth * 2 : 0);
    this._container.classList.toggle('nav-wrapper--scrollable', this.rightBorder < compareWith);
    this._scrollable = this.rightBorder < compareWith;
    this.scroll(0);
  }
}


function wrap(elem, wrapperClass: string) {
  const wrapper = el('nav-wrapper');
  elem.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, elem);
  wrapper.appendChild(elem);
  return wrapper;
}

function el(className: string): HTMLElement {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = className;
  return div;
}
```

The last thing you need to do is to apply this directive on `p-tabView` element:

```
<p-tabView tabScroller>
  ...
</p-tabView>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/BX6UTrG7XTBXS2TNChAs?p=preview)**

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/fwga5ZZaCnkNsoCajavH?open=app%2Ftab-scroller.directive.ts&layout=1)**

Comment: what is the min-width that you set it to so it shows the TabBar scroller? and in which file line is it?

Comment: It takes full width. If you want to set `min-width` see `styles.css` https://plnkr.co/edit/mxGAIs4bH6e5PzJ0hIYX?p=preview

Comment: I dont want it to take full width. I only want it to show when a certain width has been reached otherwise hide it. Where do I set that? by the way thanks a lot

Comment: Add rule `p-tabView {
  display: block;
  max-width: 600px;
}` https://plnkr.co/edit/l5PjBt0IavaJsHEen83e?p=preview

Comment: Great, Thanks a bunch bro!!